# SQL Statement using a JSP session

Tags: sql, jsp, session

I am trying to use a session that I have made in JSP in a sql statement. But having difficulties.

I captured it already and this is the SQL statement I made, but doesnt work.

```
String mysql="select * from table1 where cottCode="<%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>"";
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here you are trying to do things like this:

```
<%
    String name = session.getAttribute( "theName" );
    String mysql = "select * from table1 where cottCode=" + name;
    // then connecting MySql server using driver in JSP to execute the SQL query
%>
```

This kind of code is called JSP Scriptlet.

However, expressions like :

```
<%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>
```

are called JSP Expressions.They are used to "insert the value of a scripting language expression, converted into a string, into the data stream returned to the client. " Like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>hi, my name is <%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I don't think you can use the expression in the middle of scriptlet. Here is the tutorial on related topics, hope it'll help:
[The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I found another solution.

I used this to put it into a variable

 String pbutton=request.getParameter("T2"); 

Then for the statement....

String mysql="select * from table1 where cottCode='" + pbutton +"'";

Done. Thanks tho.

Comment: @Merked You should really be using Prepared Statements to avoid SQL injection, especially as you are using a request parameter (P2) - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db name>","<username>","<pwd>");

Statement s = c.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table where  cottCode = '"+session.getAttribute("<your session asign attribute>")+"'";
resultSet= s.executeQuery(sql);

if(resultSet.next()){

<!-- rendering part -->

}
```